# imcrop - Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am straggling with the imcrop as I wish to crop a box based on the center of an image.

Mainly, I want to crop a box 50 pixels above/below/left/right of the center but I have problem with getting the right coordinates. Furtermore, how can I mark the box over the original image.

Thanks.

The script:

```
clc;
clear;
I = imread('m83.tif');
imshow(I)
[height, width, dim] = size(I);
centerWidth=round(width/2)
centerHeight=round(height/2)
BoxBottomX=centerWidth-50;
BoxBottomY=centerHeight-50;
BoxTopX=centerWidth+50;
BoxTopY=centerHeight+50
imshow(I)
hold on
plot(centerWidth, centerHeight, '-rx')

imcrop(I, [BoxBottomX BoxBottomY BoxTopX BoxTopY]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imcrop`'s `rec` option is not the coordinates of the box, but `[xmin ymin width height]`. So If you want to crop a 100x100 box, you should do

```
imcrop(I, [BoxBottomX BoxBottomY 100 100]);
```

You can then plot a rectangle either using the points to draw 4 lines or using the function `rectangle` (note that this one also takes `[xmin ymin width height]` format)

Comment: thanks, what is the logic of using the 100 100 in the imcrop?

Comment: @user2916044 width-height. How long is your square? 100x100 (at least it is in the code you shown)